# Why my index don't update?

Tags: oracle, index, full-text-search

I have created this index

```
ORACLE/VIDEO# create index titolo_index
  2  on titolo(titolo)
  3   indextype is ctxsys.context
  4  ONLINE
  5  ;
```

I do a research

```
select * from generale where CONTAINS(titolo, '%ragazzi%')>0 order by titolo;

   159|I ragazzi della roma violenta                   |1976   |Drammatico    |1:30    |Vhs       |Italiano
```

I change from roma to Roma

```
update titolo set titolo = 'I ragazzi della Roma violenta' where idtitolo = 159;
```

And it disappear from index!
Why?

Comment: Need more information to understand how it "disappeared".  Also, please add the Oracle version you are using in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Indexing with Oracle Text](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14217/ind.htm)

> 3.3.6.1 CONTEXT Index and DML
>
> A CONTEXT index is not transactional. When you perform inserts,
>   updates, or deletes on the base table, **you must explicitly synchronize
>   the index with CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX.**